# Cannot access to admin panel after I modify .htaccess file

Tags: php

I can easily access to backend when I don't remove .php from URL but when I remove using above given file my backend doesn't redirect. Please Help. Also, can I remove .php extension only on specific page?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Below, there is the login code for my admin panel

**Login Code**

```
<?php if($_GET['loginFailed']){ ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $Translation['login failed']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-8" id="login_splash">
        <!-- customized splash content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel panel-success">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title"><strong><?php echo $Translation['sign in here']; ?></strong></h1>
                <?php if(sqlValue("select count(1) from membership_groups where allowSignup=1")){ ?>
                    <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="membership_signup.php"><?php echo $Translation['sign up']; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <form method="post" action="index.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="username"><?php echo $Translation['username']; ?></label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $Translation['username']; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="password"><?php echo $Translation['password']; ?></label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="<?php echo $Translation['password']; ?>" required>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $Translation['forgot password']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label class="control-label" for="rememberMe">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" value="1">
                            <?php echo $Translation['remember me']; ?>
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                            <button name="signIn" type="submit" id="submit" value="signIn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><?php echo $Translation['sign in']; ?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <?php if(is_array(getTableList()) && count(getTableList())){ /* if anon. users can see any tables ... */ ?>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <?php echo $Translation['browse as guest']; ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>document.getElementById('username').focus();</script>
<?php include_once("$currDir/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: so, you want to remove .php extension only for some certain files, am i right ?

Comment: Your Login code only has links for index.php (form action) and the include on the footer... These work with that .htaccess. So what is the exact error/issue you are seeing? Can you give a better example. I.E What is the actual admin url?

Comment: mywebsite.com/blogadmin the url i use for admin

Comment: @Sanjith yes. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your `.htaccess` file

```
Options -MultiViews
```

That will disable `mod_rewrite` from attempting to find an existing file to map `${REQUEST_FILENAME}` to.

Currently, a request like `/foo` will change the `${REQUEST_FILENAME}` to `foo.{extension}` if ANY files named `foo` exist.

By disabling the option above, it stops Apache from attempting to find a file and instead returns the current requested file, with or without the extension (as specified in the URL).

[Apache documentation here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: @SamanKhadgi you would need to check your file names and ensure they match the pattern you're describing in the RewriteConds. Using your htaccess with that single change was working in a test environment.